# chatContactListDidChange method firing every time chatDidLogin method sends presence timer

Tags: quickblox

---

**UPDATE** I ended up just adding a refresh button for the user to refresh the contactlist manually. I think if you guys want to get more small developers to use Quickblox for social apps like messaging and stuff you should add more documentation and examples for the Contact List. It's the core feature of any social app and yet you only devote a paragraph to it and a code snippet full of static data that cannot be applied to real-worlds apps.

For instance, one of your answers for the contact list says to do `- (void)chatDidReceiveContactAddRequestFromUser:(NSUInteger)userID{
    [[QBChat instance] confirmAddContactRequest:userID];
}` to accept a friend request. That method makes it so that a user can't accept or deny a friend request but automatically accepts every friend request received. It should allow a user the option to decline or accept the request without having to build an additional list to keep track of requests you've accepted or denied.

---

in my chatContactListDidChange method I have

```
- (void)chatContactListDidChange:(QBContactList *)contactList{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:ContactListChanged object:nil];
    NSLog(@"contact list changed");
    NSLog(@"current contact list %@", [QBChat instance].contactList);
}
```

and in chatDidLogin

```
- (void)chatDidLogin{
    // Start sending presences
    [self.presenceTimer invalidate];
    self.presenceTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5
                                     target:[QBChat instance] selector:@selector(sendPresence)
                                   userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

    if(self.loginCompletionBlock != nil){
        self.loginCompletionBlock();
        self.loginCompletionBlock = nil;
    }
}
```

Every 5 seconds the chatContactListDidChange method fires even though no users have changed their presence. Here is the log

```
2014-07-14 18:52:30.076 sample-chat[45514:3d07] -[QBChat xmppStream:didSendPresence:] -> Presence: <presence/>
2014-07-14 18:52:30.124 sample-chat[45514:90b] contact list changed
2014-07-14 18:52:30.125 sample-chat[45514:90b] current contact list 
[ContactList] 
     contacts: (
) 
     pendingApproval: (
    "  userId: 1287015, online: 0, subscriptionState: none",
    "  userId: 1289912, online: 0, subscriptionState: none",
    "  userId: 1289984, online: 0, subscriptionState: none",
    "  userId: 1287012, online: 0, subscriptionState: none",
    "  userId: 1286872, online: 0, subscriptionState: none"
)
2014-07-14 18:52:35.075 sample-chat[45514:3d07] -[QBChat xmppStream:didSendPresence:] -> Presence: <presence/>
2014-07-14 18:52:35.128 sample-chat[45514:90b] contact list changed
2014-07-14 18:52:35.128 sample-chat[45514:90b] current contact list 
[ContactList] 
     contacts: (
) 
     pendingApproval: (
    "  userId: 1287015, online: 0, subscriptionState: none",
    "  userId: 1289912, online: 0, subscriptionState: none",
    "  userId: 1289984, online: 0, subscriptionState: none",
    "  userId: 1287012, online: 0, subscriptionState: none",
    "  userId: 1286872, online: 0, subscriptionState: none"
)
2014-07-14 18:52:40.075 sample-chat[45514:401f] -[QBChat xmppStream:didSendPresence:] -> Presence: <presence/>
2014-07-14 18:52:40.129 sample-chat[45514:90b] contact list changed
2014-07-14 18:52:40.129 sample-chat[45514:90b] current contact list 
[ContactList] 
     contacts: (
) 
     pendingApproval: (
    "  userId: 1287015, online: 0, subscriptionState: none",
    "  userId: 1289912, online: 0, subscriptionState: none",
    "  userId: 1289984, online: 0, subscriptionState: none",
    "  userId: 1287012, online: 0, subscriptionState: none",
    "  userId: 1286872, online: 0, subscriptionState: none"
)
2014-07-14 18:52:45.075 sample-chat[45514:401f] -[QBChat xmppStream:didSendPresence:] -> Presence: <presence/>
2014-07-14 18:52:45.148 sample-chat[45514:90b] contact list changed
2014-07-14 18:52:45.148 sample-chat[45514:90b] current contact list 
[ContactList] 
     contacts: (
) 
     pendingApproval: (
    "  userId: 1287015, online: 0, subscriptionState: none",
    "  userId: 1289912, online: 0, subscriptionState: none",
    "  userId: 1289984, online: 0, subscriptionState: none",
    "  userId: 1287012, online: 0, subscriptionState: none",
    "  userId: 1286872, online: 0, subscriptionState: none"
)
```

I tried turning off the presence timer but then I get disconnect error `QBChat/didDisconnect, error: Error Domain=GCDAsyncSocketErrorDomain Code=7 "Socket closed by remote peer" UserInfo=0xd4b0e30 {NSLocalizedDescription=Socket closed by remote peer}`

Also, when I first login as a user the chatContactListDidChange method fires 4 times right away, here is the log of that

```
2014-07-14 19:15:23.810 sample-chat[45629:3e03] -[QBChat xmppStream:didSendIQ:] -> IQ: <iq type="get" id="561006823"><query xmlns="jabber:iq:roster"/></iq>
2014-07-14 19:15:23.810 sample-chat[45629:3e03] -[QBChat xmppStream:didSendPresence:] -> Presence: <presence/>
2014-07-14 19:15:23.810 sample-chat[45629:90b] waiting for approval = (
)
2014-07-14 19:15:23.811 sample-chat[45629:90b] contact list changed
2014-07-14 19:15:23.811 sample-chat[45629:3e03] -[QBChat xmppStream:didReceiveIQ:] -> <iq xmlns="jabber:client" to="1278228-11606@chat.quickblox.com/tigase-169625" type="result" id="561006823"><query xmlns="jabber:iq:roster"><item name="1290038-11606" subscription="none" jid="1290038-11606@chat.quickblox.com"/><item name="1286872-11606" ask="subscribe" subscription="none" jid="1286872-11606@chat.quickblox.com"/><item name="1287012-11606" ask="subscribe" subscription="none" jid="1287012-11606@chat.quickblox.com"/><item name="1287015-11606" ask="subscribe" subscription="none" jid="1287015-11606@chat.quickblox.com"/><item name="1289912-11606" ask="subscribe" subscription="none" jid="1289912-11606@chat.quickblox.com"/><item name="1289984-11606" ask="subscribe" subscription="none" jid="1289984-11606@chat.quickblox.com"/></query></iq>
2014-07-14 19:15:23.811 sample-chat[45629:90b] current contact list 
[ContactList] 
     contacts: (
) 
     pendingApproval: (
    "  userId: 1287015, online: 0, subscriptionState: none",
    "  userId: 1289912, online: 0, subscriptionState: none",
    "  userId: 1289984, online: 0, subscriptionState: none",
    "  userId: 1287012, online: 0, subscriptionState: none",
    "  userId: 1286872, online: 0, subscriptionState: none"
)
2014-07-14 19:15:23.947 sample-chat[45629:90b] waiting for approval = (
)
2014-07-14 19:15:23.946 sample-chat[45629:3e03] Request finished, response:
headers:{
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = "*";
    "Cache-Control" = "max-age=0, private, must-revalidate";
    Connection = "keep-alive";
    "Content-Type" = "application/xml; charset=utf-8";
    Date = "Tue, 15 Jul 2014 00:15:23 GMT";
    Etag = "\"6b46ffce805a218f9a8eb3082dca64b7\"";
    "QB-Token-ExpirationDate" = "2014-07-15 02:15:23 UTC";
    "QuickBlox-REST-API-Version" = "0.1.1";
    Server = "nginx/1.0.15";
    Status = "201 Created";
    "Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
    "X-Rack-Cache" = "invalidate, pass";
    "X-Request-Id" = 7122bfedd350cab031cdaf1375b28e7f;
    "X-Runtime" = "0.018427";
    "X-UA-Compatible" = "IE=Edge,chrome=1";
}
body:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<session>
  <_id>53c4729b535c123d96004e43</_id>
  <application-id type="integer">11606</application-id>
  <created-at type="datetime">2014-07-15T00:15:23Z</created-at>
  <device-id type="integer">0</device-id>
  <nonce type="integer">453</nonce>
  <token>60d472f2c86e587151bd5fa1c61db1924675fcf6</token>
  <ts type="integer">1405383323</ts>
  <updated-at type="datetime">2014-07-15T00:15:23Z</updated-at>
  <user-id type="integer">1278228</user-id>
  <id type="integer">24054</id>
</session>
error:
2014-07-14 19:15:23.947 sample-chat[45629:90b] contact list changed
2014-07-14 19:15:23.947 sample-chat[45629:90b] current contact list 
[ContactList] 
     contacts: (
) 
     pendingApproval: (
    "  userId: 1287015, online: 0, subscriptionState: none",
    "  userId: 1289912, online: 0, subscriptionState: none",
    "  userId: 1289984, online: 0, subscriptionState: none",
    "  userId: 1287012, online: 0, subscriptionState: none",
    "  userId: 1286872, online: 0, subscriptionState: none"
)
2014-07-14 19:15:23.948 sample-chat[45629:90b] waiting for approval = (
)
2014-07-14 19:15:23.948 sample-chat[45629:90b] contact list changed
2014-07-14 19:15:23.948 sample-chat[45629:90b] current contact list 
[ContactList] 
     contacts: (
) 
     pendingApproval: (
    "  userId: 1287015, online: 0, subscriptionState: none",
    "  userId: 1289912, online: 0, subscriptionState: none",
    "  userId: 1289984, online: 0, subscriptionState: none",
    "  userId: 1287012, online: 0, subscriptionState: none",
    "  userId: 1286872, online: 0, subscriptionState: none"
)
2014-07-14 19:15:23.949 sample-chat[45629:90b] waiting for approval = (
)
2014-07-14 19:15:23.949 sample-chat[45629:90b] contact list changed
2014-07-14 19:15:23.949 sample-chat[45629:90b] current contact list 
[ContactList] 
     contacts: (
) 
     pendingApproval: (
    "  userId: 1287015, online: 0, subscriptionState: none",
    "  userId: 1289912, online: 0, subscriptionState: none",
    "  userId: 1289984, online: 0, subscriptionState: none",
    "  userId: 1287012, online: 0, subscriptionState: none",
    "  userId: 1286872, online: 0, subscriptionState: none"
)
```

Comment: What are relying on to get the list of incoming add requests ?

Comment: 100% agree with documentation stuff. Quickblox documentation sucks - too many apis and developer has to figure out on their own how things work. I am facing a problem wherein [QBChat instance].contactList.contacts keep changing every time and I keep losing friends list every minute!